# Hover links disappear before you can click them

Tags: css

I've created a drop down hover list in the UL tags using CSS, but before I can get the mouse down over the links, they disappear. How can I stop this?

This is my code:

```css
#header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset         0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align: center;
}
#header ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#header ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 31px;
}
#header ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Does it look like that? http://jsfiddle.net/6NEcx/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height`

```css
#header ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:22px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your main menu is positioned at the very top of the page, it goes from 0 pixels to 30 pixels and you've left a 1 pixel gap before starting the submenu at 31 pixels. Either changing the main menu height to 31px or the top of the submenu to 30px should fix your problem.